# HTML5 multiple canvas works well in chrome, but in the case of firefox it just works only in the first canvas

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas, cross-browser

I have just started exploring HTML5 particle animation. I have tried it in a way when hovered over a canvas particle animation happens based on the mouse coordinates. It works well in chrome. But when I try to run the same code in Firefox it works well only for the first canvas and not for the other two. I couldn't figure out the issue.

This is the JSFiddle link of the code sample I tried. http://jsfiddle.net/7hEKL/15/

```
<canvas id="c1"></canvas>
<canvas id="c2"></canvas>
<canvas id="c3"></canvas>
```

Note: Try opening in both chrome and FF. I want the code to work in FF in a way it works in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position: relative` on the canvas elements.

[jsfiddle.net/7hEKL/16](http://jsfiddle.net/7hEKL/16/)